# Android - unable to access R.anim

Tags: java, android, animation, transition, r.java-file

I would like you to ask for help as I am unable to access to R.anim 
What I have done so far is, that I've created new project and wanted to use 
`overridePendingTransition` however, once I typed `R.anim.` all suggested options were:
attr, dimen, drawable, id, layout, menu, string, style...

Where could be a problem ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you importing correct R?

Comment: have you created "anim" resource folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you dont have the folder **`/res/anim`** in your project. You need to create the **`anim`** folder inside **`/res`** and put respective XML files which will do the animation.

In case you want to use inbuild animations then you should use **`android.R.anim`** instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since u didnt created Directory name `anim` in the res directory u cant access nothing there..
if u want to access Android Animation use

```
android.R.anim
```

instand.

Answer (score 0):

Create anim directory from res dir and put animation file into anim directory and clean the project then try to access.